# Unable to connect to HCNetSDK.dll to initialise HIKVision camera

Tags: dllimport, delphi-10.4-sydney, hikvision

Hope someone can help, I've trawled these pages and nothing so far works, very simple at this stage, a few lines trying to initialise the HIKVision camera by calling NET_DVR_Init, the call when creating the form to 'NET_DVR_Init'returns an error message.

All DLLs are in the same folder as the EXE so paths should not be an issue.

Using LoadLibrary only works on some DLLs, assuming dependence on other DLLs would be the cause of failure but with all HIK DLLs in the same folder surely this should not be the case ?

```
unit PTZFrm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms;

type
  TPTZ_Test = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function NET_DVR_Init(): boolean; stdcall; external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Init';

var PTZ_Test   : TPTZ_Test;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TPTZ_Test.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NET_DVR_Init();
end;

end.
```

Comment: You can use ProcessMonitor (Free tool available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which DLL, file, registry key your application are trying to access. You'll also see the DLL implicitly loaded by the DLL you explicitly load. In ProcessMonitor, set a filter on your application exename to see only it (and the DLL referenced). Additionaly, you can use CFFExplorer (https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) to check for static dependencies for HCNetSdk.dll.